# ensemble of binary classifiers vs a single multi-class classifier for multi-class classification

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision

would love to hear your thoughts on a topic. I am trying to evaluate the performance of multiple/ensemble binary classifiers for multi-class classification vs a single CNN for multiclass classifications. The goal is object classification using images as input. Looking to optimize on true positives, compute efficiency and network complexity